# Iterate on a list with a window

Tags: python, python-3.x

let say we have this list : `L =[1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ... n]`
we want to have this result by a window of 3 elements form the list :

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[2,3,4]
l3=[3,4,5]
l4=[4,5,6]
l6=[5,6,7]
l7=[6,7,8]
```

.... until we iterate over the array, and each previous array is stored in a final array,
so we end up with this:

```
final_array= [ [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[6,7,8] ]
```

how could we do this easily with a lambda function ?

Comment: `[L[i: i+window_size] for i in range(len(L) - len(L)%window_size)]`; set your `window_size` accordingly.

Comment: You do not show any effort to solve this - what did you try? Where are you stuck? What did you research?

Comment: sorry Patrick >-< I tried working with cursors and got a little lost, here's what i did  : `l=3# this is my window
new_list=[] #list to put the results 

for k in range(0,len(my_list)+l):
#     print(k)
    for j in range(-l+k,k+l):
        print(j)
#         j=k-l
        if (j<0) or (j>k+l):
#             print("true")
            new_list.append(None)
            j=j+1 
        else:    
            new_list.append(my_list[k])`

Comment: @SaraStone Add what you've tried to the question itself. Comments may get deleted. You can [edit] your question from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve it would be with a list comprehension as Ch3steR pointed out in the comments:

> `[L[i: i+window_size] for i in range(len(L) - len(L)%window_size)]`; set your window_size accordingly. –
> [Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster)

---

As for how to do it with a lambda: you can use a lambda as well and apply it onto Ch3steR'S solution:

```
L = list(range(20)) 

win_size = 4

# this is just "one kind of" indirection for the list comp to force
# usage of a lambda  - does not make it more clear though
lmd = lambda data, pos, wins: data[pos: pos + wins] 

print( [lmd(L, p, win_size) for p in range(len(L) - win_size + 1)])
```

---

From your comment:

> I tried working with cursors and got a little lost

Cursors? You can do it with iterators as well - but it will take some more code:

```
L = list(range(20))

win_size = 4

# generate iterators
iterators = [iter(L) for _ in range(win_size)]

# advance iterators: 0th points to 0th elem, 1st to the 1st elem, etc.
for pos, i in enumerate(iterators):
    for _ in range(pos):
        next(i)

# collect the values from the iterators - cut off when 1st iterator is exhausted
k = [ list(map(next, iterators)) for _ in range(len(L) - win_size + 1)]
print(k)
```

to get to

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7],
 [5, 6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10, 11], [9, 10, 11, 12],
 [10, 11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13, 14], [12, 13, 14, 15], [13, 14, 15, 16],
 [14, 15, 16, 17], [15, 16, 17, 18], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, I understand better now, but could it be also possible to make that window start at the beginning of the array as (len(my_array-window_size)) and make it untilll(len(my_array + window_size)) as we have something like this`[ [nan,nan,nan,0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7],
 [5, 6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10, 11], [9, 10, 11, 12],
 [10, 11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13, 14], [12, 13, 14, 15], [13, 14, 15, 16],
 [14, 15, 16, 17], [15, 16, 17, 18], [16, 17, 18, 19],[17, 18, 19,nan], [18, 19,nan,nan],[ 19,nan,nan,nan] ] `

Comment: You can try along the lines of `k = [ list(map(lambda x:next(x,None), iterators)) for _ in range(len(L))]` - you would have to add you [None,None,None,0] yourself

Comment: thank you very much sir (: i'll find a way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the approaches:

```
L =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
out = []
window_size = 3
if (window_size>len(L)):
    print ('Window Size is more than the list size')
else:
    for i in range(len(L)-window_size+1):
        out.append(L[i:i+window_size])
    print (out)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The third-party package [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) has a handy function called [`windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) that does exactly that:

```py
In [1]: import more_itertools

In [2]: list(more_itertools.windowed(range(1, 9), n=3))
Out[2]: [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8)]
```